# Book from the early 80s that had blood sucking borers and parasites that formed a symbiotic relationship with humans

Tags: story-identification, books

Book from the early 80s that had blood sucking borers and parasites that formed a symbiotic relationship with humans. The end of the book was a spaceship flying and two humans hanging on to the tail.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember any details of the cover art?  If the "parasites" were blood suckers, how was their relationship with humans symbiotic?

Comment: Were the "blood sucking borers" and the symbiotic parasites the same thing, or was there one blood sucking species that bored, and another species of symbiotic parasites?